# Magento 2: How to get product type in observer?

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, magento-2.1.3, product-type

I have below code.

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

         foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $this->_logger->info('Item ID: ' . $item->getProductId());
        }
        exit;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

How to get product type? What are the all options for `getAllItems`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use:

```
  $item->getProductType();
  $item->getProductOptions();
```

Comment: Can we get Customer Group Id direct? `$order->getCustomerId()` like