# Magento2 : how to add an observer only for a product type

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

In Magento2 I have a module that defines a new product type : "Myproducttype"

I would like to be able to dynamically set the price when a "Myproducttype" product is diplayed (product page).

One solution could be using an observer on the event "catalog_product_load_after", but is it possible to enable this observer only for "Myproducttype" (via xml maybe?) to avoid

```
if ($producttype=="Myproducttype") {
...}
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Of course**

Long answer: To get the product type inside observer `catalog_product_load_after`, just use the following code:

`$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$producttype = $product->getProductType();`

Ref: 
[Magento 2: How to get product type in observer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154599/magento-2-how-to-get-product-type-in-observer)